# PDO - 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064

Tags: php, pdo

I get this error when trying to update a table in the Database.

Code:

```
$stmt = $db->query("UPDATE pages SET title, desc VALUES :title, :newdesc WHERE id = '1'");
$stmt = $db->execute(array(":title" => "Awesome", ":newdesc" => "TEST"));
```

The error that I get is this, I found that it's nothing to do with other parts of my code as I put this into an empty file and the same thing happened:

Error:

```
[23-Aug-2016 15:24:02 America/Chicago] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ' desc VALUES :title, :newdesc WHERE id = '1'' at line 1' in /home/officia4/GPTScript/mitch.php:25
Stack trace:
#0 /home/officia4/GPTScript/mitch.php(25): PDO->query('UPDATE pages SE...')
#1 {main}
  thrown in /home/officia4/GPTScript/mitch.php on line 25
```

Comment: Read The Manual for an SQL UPDATE syntax: `update table set col1=1, col2=2 where id=1`

Comment: I did this before and got the same error, http://image.prntscr.com/image/20f6d9e112bd463fb7e62f2cf9833bb6.png

Comment: `desc` is a [reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html).

Comment: Maybe you're using it as short for description, or something like that, but MySQL thinks you mean DESCENDING and that's not a logical place for that.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Thanks for that answer, I did think that but I wanted to be sure, I suppose I'll have to go around changing some bits, thanks a lot, really!

Comment: If you don't want to change the column name, you can still use it if you enclose it in backticks. Personally, I'd recommend changing it if you can.